# Error: Could not resolve 'user/show/{ id: ..... }' from state ''

Tags: angular-ui-router, sails.js

i am using Sailsjs application using Angular stateprovider. i want to pass url with id. i tried more methods to pass stateprovider with id. i getting error like this  `Error: Could not resolve 'user/show/{ id: ..... }' from state '`

my code sample

```
app.js

    .state('user/show/', {
                url: '/user/show/:id',
                templateUrl: '/user/show',
                 controller:'secondCtrl'
    })

...

app.controller('secondCtrl',["$scope", "$state", "$stateParams"], function ($scope, $state, $stateParams){
    $scope.id = $stateParams.id;

    $state.go('user/show/:' +  $scope.id );
})
```

html page

```
<a ui-sref="user/show/{ id: <%= session.User.id %> }"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></a>
```

error

```
 Error: Could not resolve 'user/show/{ id: 54edd37704bc7d952524bfe1 }' from state ''
    at Object.x.transitionTo (http://localhost:1338/js/dependencies/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:16186)
    at Object.x.go (http://localhost:1338/js/dependencies/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:15755)
    at http://localhost:1338/js/dependencies/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:23364
    at http://localhost:1338/js/dependencies/angular.min.js:108:321
    at e (http://localhost:1338/js/dependencies/angular.min.js:31:267)
    at http://localhost:1338/js/dependencies/angular.min.js:34:398
```

But page could not be changed ..
So , please help me...

Answer (score 0):

StateProvider doesn't work in such way. You have no state with the name `user/show/:` so you can not resolve it.

Try:

```
$state.go('user/show/', {
    id: $scope.id
});
```